# Get all days of month for calculation in SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have never done this before. Now what I want is that I have a report to produce which comprises of the total no of patients present on the bed on each day of the month. Finally I will take a count of all the days as a grand total.

For example: if January is considered, then 1st jan patients till midnight present + 2nd jan patients till midnight present + .... + 31st Janpatients till midnight present = GRAND TOTAL.

Can I do it in SQL Server using cursor or something like that or should can I use C# and SQL Server in combination?

Comment: yes, you can do this in C# and SQL Server. But what have you tried so far that is not working?

Comment: I have not tried any thing..just stuck with the thot of using which oprion just sql server(cursor,temp tables) or C# + sql server(which will be slow as call be given)